# How to calculate the product from combinations of several vectors in R?

Tags: r, vector, combinations, permutation, multiplication

I feel it hard to give an accurate title, though I have tried my best. Here's my problem.

```
a = 1/(1:10)
b = 3/(1:10)
c = 1/(1:5)
d = 1/(1:11)
```

I would like to get a vector `e`, such that `e` consists of the product calculated from the combinations of values chosen from `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

For example, supposing there are two vectors `{1, 2}` and `{3, 4}`, I would like to get a vector like this `{1 * 3, 1 * 4, 2 * 3, 2 * 4} = {3, 4, 6, 8}`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`expand.grid` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51849390/4891738) is OK, but in mathematics there is an elegant **Kronecker product**.

R has a function `kronecker`, but it takes two vectors at a time, so we need `Reduce` for a recursive application:

```
oo <- Reduce(kronecker, list(a, b, c, d))
```

Alternatively, use `outer` (the workhorse of `kronecker`):

```
rr <- Reduce(outer, list(a, b, c, d))
```

This is more user-friendly, as `rr[i, j, u, v]` gives you `a[i] * b[j] * c[u] * d[v]`.

---

**Remark 1**

Note that elements in `oo` and `rr` differ in order. Because for two vectors `a` and `b`:

```
kronecker(a, b)  ## a[1] * b, a[2] * b ...
outer(a, b)      ## a * b[1], a * b[2] ...
```

Thus the following use of `kronecker` produces a result identical to `rr`.

```
zz <- Reduce(kronecker, list(d, c, b, a))
dim(zz) <- c(length(a), length(b), length(c), length(d))
```

---

**Remark 2**

The method can be adapted to do `a[i] + b[j] + c[u] + d[v]`, by replacing the default operation `"*"` in `outer` and `kronecker` to `"+"`. For example:

```
Reduce(function (x, y) outer(x, y, "+"), list(a, b, c, d))
```

---

**Remark 3**

[johannes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51849390/4891738) can be improved. That row-wise application of `apply` is a performance killer. We can do the following to get a result consistent with `rr`.

```
xx <- Reduce("*", expand.grid(a, b, c, d))
dim(xx) <- c(length(a), length(b), length(c), length(d))
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this

```
a <- c(1, 2)
b <- c(3, 4)
```

And now for the problem that you stated:

```
apply(expand.grid(a, b), 1, prod)

x <- list(
  a=c(1/(1:10)),
  b=c(3/(1:10)),
  c=c(1/(1:5)),
  d=c(1/(1:11))
)

apply(expand.grid(x), 1, prod)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to do this for two lists. It's not the most efficient one but gets the job done.

```
my_function <- function(x, y) {
  result <- c()
  for(i in x) {
    for(j in y) {
      result <- c(result, i * j)
    }
  }
  return(result)
}

x = c(1, 2)
y = c(3, 4)

my_function(x, y)
# [1] 3 4 6 8
```